# Can I use the sync voltage, OR the audio output from a Korg Volca to control a Moog Little Phatty CV input?

Tags: midi, effects, control

I'm not looking for necessarily *clean* results, as this is simply experimentation.  But I also don't want to fry the CV in on my Moog.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES!  You can!

But it sounds awful.  I ran the audio output of a kick drum into the filter CV, and while it was certainly triggering the filter, it was very rough sounding.

Maybe some experimentation on the volume and tone of the output might yield better results.